# How to control master mixer volume in windows 7 using mixer api?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, audio

In windows XP, it is quite easy to control master volume of a mixer device by setting volume of destination line using mixer api.It can be easily tested by sdk sample application provided by Microsoft.But in case of windows 7 whenever I open a mixer device in my application it shows it as new volume application and I am able to control only volume of my application.Not able to control complete sound of system.Can anyone suggest me how to control complete sound of speaker which will affect sound of all running application.

[image]

How can I change speakers volume using my application in windows 7 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the method you're looking for is `SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar`.

A short example in C (sorry for the `lpVtbl`s):

```
BOOL AddMasterVolumeLevelScalar(float fMasterVolumeAdd)
{
    IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice *defaultDevice = NULL;
    IAudioEndpointVolume *endpointVolume = NULL;
    HRESULT hr;
    float fMasterVolume;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(&XIID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &XIID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, (LPVOID *)&deviceEnumerator);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = deviceEnumerator->lpVtbl->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(deviceEnumerator, eRender, eConsole, &defaultDevice);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = defaultDevice->lpVtbl->Activate(defaultDevice, &XIID_IAudioEndpointVolume, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, (LPVOID *)&endpointVolume);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                if(SUCCEEDED(endpointVolume->lpVtbl->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(endpointVolume, &fMasterVolume)))
                {
                    fMasterVolume += fMasterVolumeAdd;

                    if(fMasterVolume < 0.0)
                        fMasterVolume = 0.0;
                    else if(fMasterVolume > 1.0)
                        fMasterVolume = 1.0;

                    if(SUCCEEDED(endpointVolume->lpVtbl->SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(endpointVolume, fMasterVolume, NULL)))
                        bSuccess = TRUE;
                }

                endpointVolume->lpVtbl->Release(endpointVolume);
            }

            defaultDevice->lpVtbl->Release(defaultDevice);
        }

        deviceEnumerator->lpVtbl->Release(deviceEnumerator);
    }

    return bSuccess;
}
```

In case the GUIDs are not defined:

```
const static GUID XIID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = { 0xA95664D2, 0x9614, 0x4F35, { 0xA7, 0x46, 0xDE, 0x8D, 0xB6, 0x36, 0x17, 0xE6 } };
const static GUID XIID_MMDeviceEnumerator = { 0xBCDE0395, 0xE52F, 0x467C, { 0x8E, 0x3D, 0xC4, 0x57, 0x92, 0x91, 0x69, 0x2E } };
const static GUID XIID_IAudioEndpointVolume = { 0x5CDF2C82, 0x841E, 0x4546, { 0x97, 0x22, 0x0C, 0xF7, 0x40, 0x78, 0x22, 0x9A } };
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work. Definitions of XIID_IAudioEndpointVolume and XIID_MMDeviceEnumerator are missing.

Comment: Those values don't work for me. My solution is using `__uuidof( MMDeviceEnumerator )`. Props for the effort, I have no idea where did you pluck those value from. ( Minor rant: `__uuidof` is black magic )

Comment: I don't really remember, but Google shows [this](https://code.google.com/p/winuae-mod/source/browse/trunk/winuae+2.01/od-win32/sound.c?r=155), so that might be the source. These values work for me, at least on Windows 7 to 8.1.